# Substitute in what is known in conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

**Motivation**:
It might appear intuitive that $E(f(X,Y)|Y=y)=E(f(X,y)|Y=y)$, i.e. we just substitute in what is known in the conditional expectation. However, I want to prove this rigorously using the definition and properties of conditional expectation defined in measure theory.

**The general setting**:
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, consider a sub-sigma algebra $\mathcal{G}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$ and random elements $X: \Omega\rightarrow S$, $Y: \Omega\rightarrow T$. Assume $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. Also, let $f$ be a real-valued measurable function $f: S\times T\rightarrow R$ such that $E(f(X,Y))<\infty$.

Recall: $E(f(X,Y)|\mathcal{G}) $ is defined as the unique (up to a.s. equivalence) $\mathcal{G}$-measurable function in $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P|_{\mathcal{G}})$ such that $\int_A f(X,Y) dP = \int_A E(f(X,Y)|\mathcal{G}) dP$ for all $A\in \mathcal{G}$. Any properties deduced from this definition are allowed to use.

**Questions**: 
(1). Can we deduce that $E(f(X,Y)|\mathcal{G})(w) = E(f(X,Y(w))|\mathcal{G})(w)$ $P-$almost surely in $w\in \Omega$? 
(2). **If (1) is not true** in general, then under what regularity conditions does (1) hold?

(Edit: by the independence lemma, (1) holds under the assumption of X is independent of Y, when X and Y are random vectors, but assuming independence seems too strong)

Comment: what is your definition of $\operatorname{E}[f(X,Y)|Y=y]$? Otherwise we can define $\operatorname{E}[f(X,Y)|Y=y]:=\operatorname{E}[f(X,Y)|Y=Y(\omega )]$ for every $\omega \in Y^{-1}(y)$

Comment: What you claim is 'intuitive' looks suspect to me. You may provide references of where you have seen it used

Comment: Look at Lemma 2.3.4 in "Stochastic Calculus for Finance II" by Steven E. Shreve, you'll see under which conditions your (1) is true.

Comment: @Masacroso yes my definition for $E[f(X,Y)|Y=y]$ is exactly as you stated: $E[f(X,Y)|Y=Y(w)]$ for every $w\in Y^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: @Snoop Hmm, what I meant by "intuitive" is just a handwavy perception that I had from previous elementary probability courses. There's no reliable reference for that, but still I'm just posting my question using that "intuition" as a starting point to formally prove it.

Comment: @RobertoPalermo Thanks for the pointer. The book essentially establishes (1) under the case for random vectors and independence between X, Y. I'm craving to see if at least this independence can be removed.

Comment: We have $$E(f(X, Y) \mid Y)I(Y = y) = E(f(X, y) \mid Y)I(Y = y)$$ almost surely. The $E(f(X, Y) \mid Y = y)$ is the value of $E(f(X, Y) \mid Y)$ on the set $\{Y = y\}$.

Comment: @Mason I think this shows that when we query the value for a particular y, it is equivalent (up to a.s.) to replace $E(f(X,Y)|Y=y)$ by $E(f(X,y)|Y=y)$ since modifying on that y alone preserves a.s. equivalence. If we want to consider all possible y's, i.e. Y(w), as we go as stated in (1), I think we might need to resort to methods such as regular conditional probability as proposed by Jason because it is exactly the same motivation (able to show on single element, but not as a whole) that prompts the development of regular conditional probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sufficient condition for (1) to be true is that there exists a regular conditional distribution for $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$. This is true, for instance, if $S$ is a standard Borel space. A regular conditional distribution for $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$ is a function $\mu(A,\omega)$, where $\mu(\cdot,\omega)$ is a probability measure on $S$ for each $\omega$, $\mu(A,\cdot)$ is a random variable for each measurable $A$, and $P(X\in A\mid\mathcal{G})=\mu(A)$ a.s., for each measurable $A$. In this case, if $Z$ is a version of $E[f(X,Y)\mid\mathcal{G}]$, then we have
$$
Z(\omega) = \int f(x,Y(\omega))\,\mu(dx, \omega)
$$
for almost every $\omega$. In particular, if we define
$$
Z(y) = \int f(x,y)\,\mu(dx),
$$
then $Z(y)$ is a version of $E[f(X,y)\mid\mathcal{G}]$ for every $y$, and $Z(Y)$ is a version of $E[f(X,Y)\mid\mathcal{G}]$. See Chapter 5 of *Foundations of Modern Probability* by Olav Kallenberg for further details.

Comment: Thank you for the method. I studied a bit about regular conditional distribution before using this book. However, there are two things I'm not certain. The first thing is the first equation you listed. To my knowledge, regular conditional probability tells us $E[f(X,Y)|\mathcal{G}] = \int f(x, Y) \mu(dx, \cdot)$ for almost every $w$; although it appears intuitive that when we query the value of the random variable on the right (the result of integral) at w, we may just feed w into all random quantities ($\mu$ and $Y$ in this case), but I have no clue how to justify this formally.

Comment: The second point I’m unsure about is the final implication. If I’m not mistaken, the second equation only holds for any fixed y. 

So, the logic goes like: fix y, possibly excluding a set of w of measure 0 denoted by N_y, both of your equations hold; then for w such that Y(w)=y and w is not in N_y, my (1) holds for this particular w. When we iterate all possible y, I think the union of N_y may not be negligible, but my (1) requires it to hold for almost all w.

Comment: The integrals on the right are defined $\omega$-wise. We fix an $\omega$, obtain a measure $\mu(\cdot,\omega)$, and then we have an ordinary integral. What you describe about feeding $\omega$ into $\mu$ and $Y$ is necessary in order to even make sense of these integral expressions. It's part of how they're defined.

Comment: Regarding the second comment, it's a little hand-wavy to even be evaluating a conditional expectation at $\omega$ in the first place, since the conditional expectation is only defined up to a set of measure zero. Given that, I have edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. It now makes more sense. I guess the crucial step at the end that I didn't see at first is that when we substitute Y into Z(y), which is a function in w for all y, Z(Y) is a function in w such that when we query (Z(Y))(w), it actually gives Z(Y(w))(w).